# Angular2 : X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: heroku, angular, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am struggling with this issue today as I am implementing a cross-site API call. The worst thing is it works well from my local environment but once on heroku, it fails with the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all. Request header field X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here is the function triggering the call:

```
  let observable = this._http
    .get(GEO_API_URL + query)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .do(val => {
      this.cache = val;
      observable = null;
    })
    .share();

  return observable;
```

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: That needs to be configured no the server and is not related to Angular2. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Thanks for your answer Günter. I know it's not Angular but there should be some kind of workaround ? But when I try to replace the Access-Control-Request-Headers, it says "Refused to set unsafe Header".

Comment: I don't know where you replace the header and I don't know what workaround you mean. Angular is not involved in this, the preflight request is created by your browser not by Angular. Only after the response to the preflight request contains the correct headers, the browser is doing the actual request initiated by Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I didn't say it was angular, I mentioned angular on the title because that's the technology I'm using here. It works from local but once on heroku it fails... That's it.

Comment: If you access a different URL (even when only the port is different) the browser requires the CORS headers. You'll have to look up how to configure them on Heroku.

Answer (score 47):

Had the same issue.
In my case the reason was that in my Chrome cookies was saved X-XSRF-TOKEN field. And somehow Chrome added header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-xsrf-token' to OPTION request. In Firefox the same page works fine, in incognito mode Chrome - too. 
So I've just delete this cookies field (X-XSRF-TOKEN) and that's all.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a hard time trying to find an answer for a similar problem

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad to help)

Comment: Thank you so much @zahar_g . But now I wonder. What about when production? Is it gonna happen to my users?

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had to add the '**x-xsrf-token**' value to 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' header:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-xsrf-token')
```

see [AngularJS: POST Data to External REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289195/angularjs-post-data-to-external-rest-api)

Comment: I have an application that has X-XSRF-TOKEN as a default for all requests.  This is the easiest way to allow the CORS request to go through.

Answer (score 2):

I cleared cookies, this solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me in java (expose the headers and then include in the allow headers). This will then show in your HttpResponse object:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "header1");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "header2");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "header3");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, header1, header2, header3, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `x-xsrf-token` keyword is not in response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

I solved this problem in java using following solution:

```
rsp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,TRACE,CONNECT");
                rsp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "cache-control,content-type,hash-referer,x-requested-with, x-xsrf-token");
                if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
                    rsp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    return;
                }
```